# Solid-state LVDT emulation

Tags: microcontroller, transformer, inductor, emulator

I have a 1970s linear variable displacement transformer and I would like to create a limited solid-state equivalent. This transformer has two coils. I do not know the number of windings.

From making measurements I know the inductances of both coils and the coupling factor for 15 different positions of the core. It is acceptable to me if the solid state version only emulates four positions.

Here is an example for a core position of 'zero': L1 = 731 mH, L2 = 375 mH, coupling factor = 0.94065

I would like to control the emulated position of the core using a microcontroller, so if that means transistors switching between four different sets of components then that is OK.

I know an inductor can be modeled using a gyrator and I could use a programmable resistor configured by the microcontroller to perhaps set the inductance, but how would I couple two gyrators together emulating a specific coupling factor?

How about having the microcontroller generate the coupling? Sensing the input to one coil and generating the output waveform on the other? Practical?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Idea: actual LVDT attached to a servo

Comment: @user253751 I want to get away from the bulky mechanical device.

Comment: Idea (I'm not sure if it will work) - use a DC bias on a regular transformer to drive the core into saturation and decrease inductance and coupling.

Comment: My knowlege of LVDTs is limited, but being a transformer I would think the actual inductance is irrelevant and the coupling factor is the significant parameter. What happens if you put a variable resistor in series with the secondary of the LVDT with it in the highest coupling position and vary the resistance? Does this have the same result of moving the LVDT position?

Comment: An LVDT is a transformer. Ideally the LVDT will just output an AC voltage proportional to the distance of the core from the null point and proportional to the excitation voltage (in or out of phase). So an analog multiplier plus a DAC would work.